# Ledctl does not work with AMD Epyc platform

Tags: linux, centos, amd

I need to highlight a disk on an amd platform. On Intel I use ledctl, this solves the problem. For amd ledctl does not work. I tried to look for analogues but nothing worked. How to turn on the disk error LED on an AMD platform?

OS Centos 8

Ledctl Log

```
Nov 21 12:03:24   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.4/0000:42:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:24   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.3/0000:41:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:24   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:03.2/0000:62:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:24   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:03.1/0000:61:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:41   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.4/0000:42:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:41   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.3/0000:41:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:41   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:03.2/0000:62:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 21 12:03:41   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:03.1/0000:61:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
```

Ledmon Log

```
Nov 23 12:52:41   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.4/0000:44:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 23 12:52:51   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.3/0000:43:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 23 12:52:51   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.4/0000:44:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 23 12:53:01   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.3/0000:43:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
Nov 23 12:53:01   ERROR: controller discovery: /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.4/0000:44:00.0 - enclosure management not supported.
```

smartctl --test=offline /dev/sda does not work
hdparm -tT /dev/sda The green HDD LED blinked, but I want to see a second red error LED